# An Internal Error Occured

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am getting some internal error while building, launching, executing rapc in eclipse for Blackberry development.
I am not getting why it is coming all of a sudden.
I tried creating a new project and copying my files to the new project but it didn't work.

> An internal error occurred during: "Deploying Default".java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You may want to provide additional info to get some responses.

Comment: Do you have the blackberry JDE installed?

Answer (score 1):

got solved by re-installing eclipse plugin for Blackberry

Answer (score 0):

Facing same problem, but got the solution by creating `new workspace`.